# Python Import Hook to Prepend Path

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to fix my "library" imports given QuantConnect's directory structure. The way they organize "user libraries" is as such:

Let's say I make a project called "Project" which by a UI selection has selected a library called "Utilities". QC creates the following folder structure:

```
.
├── Project
    |── main.py
├── Library
    ├── Utilities
        ├── Whatever.py
```

However a problem arises by way of how QC imports the "Utilities" library. It does so by importing all of the contents of the directory while removing the top-level directory name. You can think of the resulting structure as such:

```
.
├── Project
    |── main.py
    ├── Whatever.py
```

As a result, I can no longer use `from Utilities.Whatever import *`. So to mitigate that issue on their platform, I put all of the contents of each library into a folder of the same name. So the original structure now looks like:

```
.
├── Project
    |── main.py
├── Library
    ├── Utilities
        ├── Utilities
            ├── Whatever.py
```

...and the final structure looks like:

```
.
├── Project
    |── main.py
    ├── Utilities
        ├── Whatever.py
```

Now imports work as expected. Only now they only work as expected through QC's online "algorithm lab", but not locally! I can't change this layout due to how QC imports their user libraries, so I need to create a python import hook that will try and find an environment variable that if it isn't set, will default to not implementing the hook; but when found, it is assumed to be running in a non-QC environment and should prepend the 1st level directory name of the import. i.e., translating `from Utilities.Whatever import *` to `from Utilities.Utilities.Whatever import *`.

I've read many articles/tutorials about python's import hooks but they all provide widely varying solutions to not-quite-what-I'm-looking-for problems, and I'm stuck failing to understand the inner workings of the hook structure.

Comment: Simple. Just add a `try-catch` block in the import. Try the QC import syntax , catch ImportError and then try your own local import syntax.

Comment: Again I have no idea what QuantConnect is, but I’m literally just rolling with it

Comment: In that first case, I'm not sure what you mean by "importing all of the contents of the directory". Is `Library/Utilities` in `sys.path`? In fact, what is in `sys.path`?! it should hold all of the directories that python scans. I think you could write a setup.py at the same level as main.py that searches for packages in Library/Utilities. Then do a "developer install" with pip. Then you could just use the same structure as the web site.

Comment: QuantConnect is a trading platform that allows people to use C#/Python to code up algorithms. What I mean by importing all of the contents, is that when I (through the UI of the algorithm lab) select the Utilities library as a library reference for the Project, all of the contents of Utilities appears in the Project root directory, but not the Utilities directory itself. I made several directory illustrations stating as much.

Comment: @rv.kvetch there are too many files that reference these Utilities imports to do that efficiently.

Comment: I see. In that case I would suggest putting importing the module itself, but in a new `utilities_imports.py` file. For example in that stub module just have a line `import <path to utilities module> as utils` with the same try-catch logic as mentioned. Then you would need to update all other files to import `utils` from `utilities_imports` instead, but that should make it more manageable I believe

Comment: I have already implemented a half-way solution wherein I made a function that runs importlib as a shim. However I still need to reference Utilities.Utilities.Whatever in all of my files in order to get that function and I'm back at square one when I want to switch between developing locally and when using the cloud. I'd rather put the shim in some sort of global context wherein all modules have access to it instead of requiring an explicit import to get the function. That where I figured python's Import Hooks come into play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating two files named 'Library.py'. One was empty and placed in `Library/Utilities/Utilities`, and the other (not empty) was placed in `Library/Utilities`. So now, when I type `import Utilities.Library` in any given script being run in the QC environment, nothing happens (as it should) because the Library.py file being referenced is empty; when it runs in a local environment, the following code executes:

```
import os
import sys

# Use env variable to ensure we only update the sys path once
env_check = 'Checked-Library-Environment'
if os.environ.get(env_check) is None:
    os.environ[env_check] = 'True'

    _path = None
    path = os.getcwd()
    target = "Library"
    library = None

    # Stop searching when we've reached the root
    while path is not _path:
        test_path = os.path.join(path, target)
        if os.path.isdir(test_path):
            library = test_path
            break
        _path = path
        path = os.path.dirname(path)

    # If we've found the Library directory, add its contents to the module path list
    if library is not None:
        for name in os.listdir(library):
            path = os.path.join(library, name)
            if not path in sys.path:
                sys.path.append(path)
```